# What is the meaning of "being the type to point fingers"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Here is the whole sentence:

> Being the type to point fingers, this person decides to run a git blame to see who last modified this line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being someone who blames or accuses. The idiom is visual ..

Comment: Not merely someone who (in one instance) blames, but someone who habitually finds fault.